# VS2005: How can I print a selected piece of code without the highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio, printing, background-color, selected

When I want just one piece of code printed, I can select it, and press the "print" menu command; what follows is a printout of the correct piece of code, but with a highlighted background.

Any tip on how to get a selected piece of code printed as I would see it, unselected?

Comment: Each time you print code, a tree is being cut.... why print code ?

Comment: This issue seems to be for VS2005 and/or earlier VS. I do not get highlighted background for VS2008. Time to upgrade?

Comment: I _do_ print as little as possible :)  But it saves my eyes when studying a complex piece of code on paper.  That, in turn, will postpone my having to wear glasses, which will save a tree's worth of energy (considering the production cost, the price of the eye doctor, the gasoline burnt when driving there...)

Comment: But thanks for reminding me: I concur.

Comment: @Dani.. There are far more useless things that contribute to unnecessary deforestation. Printing out a piece of code to take with you or to save your eyes from strain is NOT one of them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print selection.
Works good on VS2008, without the Background.

Comment: the so called 'highlite' was actually the background color, which isn't 'default' on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, if it's only a small fragment (say within a screen size), perform a screencapture and print that.

PS: Print on recycled paper if possible. We need the trees. :P